# Adding default identity results in page not found in dot net 6

Tags: asp.net, identity, scaffolding

I am working on an dot net 6 application and have trouble with adding default identity. What I have done is I created another project where I scaffolded Identity in it. This new project works fine but when I copy/paste all of the elements done by the scaffold in my real projects it gives me "This localhost page can't be found."

My program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Thriftshop.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Thriftshop.DataAccess;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); // THIS LINE
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
//builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{//
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication(); ;
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


app.Run();
```

If I remove the AdddefaultIdentity line it works fine. All my packages are the same version (6.0.12). What could be the issue?

- Changed packages version; Expected a bug in an identity package.
- Checked the DbContext file to see if there was anything wrong with it.
- Added the option (options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true) in AddDefaultEntity

Comment: "I copy/paste all of the elements done by the scaffold " Do you have  scaffold  views ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I scaffolded identity which gives me razor pages for account management which I copied/pasted in the Areas folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am following the course by Brughen. I solved it by copy/pasting from this github repo: https://github.com/bhrugen/Bulky at the "Scaffold Identity" commit and changed the files/models that I need.